# Get item by Displayname using fast query in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

I have created a vanilla sitecore 8.1 MVC instance and trying to get **home** item by displayname using fast query  but getting null value:

[image]

Do I need to do any configuration settings in web.config.I am passing "Home" in this function.
I have set useDisplayName="true" attribute in `<LinkManager>` element in Sitecore.config file also.

Thanks

Comment: I understand you're trying to get the home item but is there a specific reason you are trying to do it this way?

Comment: this is just for demonstration I have already code in my project written in this way that's why have to do like that If this will work I will get to know if any other configuration required because this is simple code and it should work. might be I am missing something.

Comment: Understood. The code and syntax looks correct to me, however there are better ways to query for the "home item" of a site.

Comment: I know but here my concern is not getting home item ...my concern is how to write fast query to get any item using @__Display Name attribute

Comment: Right, your code is correct. It could be case sensitive so maybe you need to try *home* instead of *Home*?

Comment: You can also try `@__Display name` instead of `@__Display Name`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to query the field by its name with a lowercase "n":

```
fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__Display name='{0}']
```

Comment: I tried with lower case but didn't get then I went to Appearance section in sitecore and upadated the Display name attribute with "home" value and it's worked out